# Verificar índice em array de objetos pela propriedade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-5

Ao clicar em um elemento, eu recebo um id.
Com isso eu faço for em um array e descubro qual objeto tem o mesmo id, e preciso remover todos os objetos com mesmo id.

```
 function onRemove(city) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].id === city.id){
            (remover objeto do array)
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Não coloque a solução na pergunta. Não é dessa forma que o StackOverflow funciona. Se o @RicardoPontual forneceu a solução que queria então marca-la como certa já indica que é solução. Caso contrário e se achar que é algo diferente, pode você mesmo responder à sua questão com o que considera solução.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar `splice` para remover um elemento por índice de um array:

```
array.splice(i, 1);
```

No exemplo, ele remove 1 elemento a partir do índice `i`

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

**EDIT:** Um exemplo atendendo aos comentários:

```
  function onRemove(city) {
      var removeu = true;
      while(removeu) {
         removeu = remover(city);
      }
  }

  function remover(city) {
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].id === city.id){
            array.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

**EDIT 2**: uma solução usando `Array.filter`:

```
var novoarray = array.filter(function(a){return a.id != city.id});
```

Exemplo:

```js
var array = [ {id: 1, city: 'AAA'}, {id: 2, city: 'BBB'}, {id: 3, city: 'CCC'} ];
var city = {id: 2, city: 'BBB'};

var novoarray = array.filter(function(a){return a.id != city.id});
console.log(novoarray);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, tentei isso, mas cada vem q eu removo um valor do array o valor de `i` diminui e não acaba varrendo no array até o fim

Comment: Tem dois pontos aqui: 1) você quer procurar um item específico, que só vai ter um e remover? Se for basta usar um `break` e encerrar o `for` 2) Pode haver vários itens e quer remover todos. Nesse outro caso, precisar fazer varias chamadas À *function* e alterá-la para retornar algo que informe que não tem mais itens para remover. Daí, você vai chamando até que remova todos os itens, usando a mesma solução com `break` para sair cada vez que achar um item e remover

Comment: Alternativa 2, vai ter vários, e ai preciso remover todos os objetos que tem o mesmo id dentro do array.

Comment: exemplo : `var remover=true; while(remover) { remover= functionRemover(city); }`

Comment: editei a resposta com um exemplo dessa lógica

Comment: Boa Ricardo! Esse filtro era o que eu precisava!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `splice`, e quando achar uma ocorrência, você decrementa -1 no `i`:

```js
var array = [
   {
   "id":"1"
   },
   {
   "id":"2"
   },
   {
   "id":"1"
   },
   {
   "id":"4"
   },
   {
   "id":"1"
   },
   {
   "id":"1"
   },
   {
   "id":"1"
   }
   ];

var city = { "id":"1" };

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].id === city.id){
      array.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
   }
}
  
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma (UPDATE: Atualizei para ES5 e também para excluir vários):

```
function onRemove(city) {
    var citiesFound = array.filter(function (a) {
        return a.id === city.id;
    });

    citiesFound.forEach(function(c) {
        var index = array.indexOf(c);

        if (index >= 0) {
            array.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas preciso utilizar apenas ecmascript-5, mesmo assim vou fazer um teste

Comment: Editei para ES5, espero que te atenda, valeu.

Comment: Eu joguei no babel e deu esse resultado tbm, fiz o teste, mas quando existe mais de um objeto com o mesmo id ele não remove todos... Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Prontinho @BrunoCabral, editado para atender mais de um item com o mesmo id

Comment: Obrigado Leandro! Eu utilizei o filtro que o Ricardo Pontual me passou nas respostas a cima e resolveu!

Comment: `var cityFound = array.filter(function (a) {
          return a.id != city.id;
      });
 array = cityFound;`

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode usar o `indexOf` para identificar a posição onde o seu valor (id da cidade) se encontra.

Após isso, você pode remover o item com `splice`. Nele você informa a posição onde deseja começar a fazer a remoção, e o número de itens que deseja remover a partir daquele (1 no seu caso, eu acredito). Além disso, o retorno do `splice` é o novo array com as remoções feitas.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
function onRemove(city) {
    var posicao = array.indexOf(city);
    array.splice(posicao, 1);
}
```

Nota: o suporte dos navegadores para o `indexOf` é limitado. Não suportado no Internet Explorer 7 e 8.

É claro que se o `indexOf` não funcionar muito bem para você, é possível localizar a cidade em questão da forma como você fez (varrendo com o for). Porém, acredito que o `splice` seja útil.